# Papa Parse is too fast

Tags: mysql, json, papaparse

I am using Papa Parse to read CSV files that usually have many duplicate rows. 
Through the STEP callback, each row is POSTed to an API that checks if the row is a duplicate before adding it to a MySQL database. The problem is, Papa Parse fires the next row (and POST request) before the previous one is added to the database. Seeing as duplicate rows are often close to each other, I end up with duplicate entries in my database. Is this solvable within Papa Parse?

Possible solution: Let the JSON compile and pass each row to an Async function that waits for each POST request to be completed.

```
$.get('file.csv', function(data) {
    Papa.parse(data, {
        header: true,
        skipEmptyLines: true,
        step: function(results, parser) {
            var product = results.data[0];
            $.ajax({ 
                url: '/api/create',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $.param({'product':product}),
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Use javascript delays ([check here how](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)).... without code, instances, or even details, we cant help further

Comment: Couldn't you use some form of lock?

Comment: You must enforce uniqueness at a database level constraints first, you can't trust  the API client to always behave, even if you fix this one particular issue

Comment: I updated my post @Bonatti, a delay would work but doesn't seem like the best solution.

Comment: How come you're checking if something is duplicate before adding it to MySQL? MySQL is the tool for this, using unique constraints ensures you won't end up with duplicates.

Comment: Yes, however, if the row exists I want to send it another route.

Comment: Ok, that's why you can just insert and if you receive an exception - that particular record exists and you can send it somewhere else. I don't see a reason for using some other API for integrity - that's solely database's job.

Comment: @Mjh, I guess you are right

Answer (score 6):

Papa Parse supports `pausing` and `resuming` (maybe not when you posted your question). Respectively, you pause and resume using `pause()` and `resume()`. For example:

```
    step: function(results, parser) {
        parser.pause();
        //do your stuff that needs to complete before next row is given
        parser.resume();
    }
```